# Is there a way to determine if there is a float on a page?

Tags: floats, conditionals

I am busy developing some code to draw layouts. Part of the code overlays the layout as shown in the images below:

[image][image]

The black arrows to the side of the images, denote the `\topfraction` and `\bottomfraction`, parameters. It will be nice to only show them, if a float exists in that position. Is it possible to detect a float and its position?

(Aim of the package, is to show in one glance all the geometry parameters and also draw a grid, see the thin light teal lines).

Comment: `fancyhdr` has some code for detecting floats, including an `\iffloatpage` macro that might be helpful.

Comment: @AlanMunn Your suggestion worked well, if you want to add a line or  two, I will accept it as an answer, otherwise  will accept David's for his explanation.

Comment: Yiannis: since I assumed you were looking for code rather than a package solution, I'll leave it to David's expertise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

within the output routine (which is where I assume you are adding your overlay) you could examine

```
    \@freelist     : List of empty boxes for placing new floats.
    \@toplist      : List of floats to go at top of current column.
    \@midlist      : List of floats in middle of current column.
    \@botlist      : List of floats to go at bottom of current column.
    \@deferlist    : List of floats to go after current column.
    \@dbltoplist   : List of double-col. floats to go at top of current
                     page.
    \@dbldeferlist : List of double-column floats to go on subsequent
                     pages.
```

Or you may prefer to patch

```
%  \begin{macro}{\@flupdates}
% \changes{v1.0f}{1993/12/05}{Command added}
%    This updates everything when a float is placed.
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*2ekernel|autoload>
\def \@flupdates #1#2#3{%
   \global \advance #1\m@ne
   \global \advance \@colnum \m@ne
   \@tempdima -\ht\@currbox
   \advance \@tempdima
     -\ifx #3\@empty \textfloatsep \else \floatsep \fi
   \global \advance #2\@tempdima
   \global \advance \@colroom \@tempdima
   \@cons #3\@currbox
}
```

so that it updates your data structures in addition to the output routine internals.

---

Looking at `fancyhdr`. It uses the first method I suggested. For example it saves `\@toplist` (in `\topfloat`) before latex sets the column so that it is still defined at the point that the header is set. Then `\iftopfloat` does a simple `ifx` test to see if this is empty.

*However* if it is *not* empty then it is a list of (indexes of) box registers that hold the floats that were put at the top of the column. So you can tell how many floats are in that area by the length of the list. However you can't get the extent because by the time the header is called the floats have already been added and the float boxes cleared and recycled.

So this document (which doesn't load any package but uses relevant fancyhdr definitions) can test if there are any top floats and if so count the list and report how many floats are there (0 1 and 2 in this document) but when it iterates over the list to report the sizes of the floats it gets nothing as the boxes have been cleared.

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\textheight{20\baselineskip}
\raggedbottom

\makeatletter
\newif\iffootnote
\let\latex@makecol\@makecol
\def\@makecol{\ifvoid\footins\footnotetrue\else\footnotefalse\fi
\let\topfloat\@toplist\let\botfloat\@botlist\latex@makecol}
\def\iftopfloat#1#2{\ifx\topfloat\empty #2\else #1\fi}
\def\ifbotfloat#1#2{\ifx\botfloat\empty #2\else #1\fi}
\def\iffloatpage#1#2{\if@fcolmade #1\else #2\fi}

\def\ps@foo{%
\def\@oddhead{%
T: \iftopfloat{yes
               [{\count@\z@ \def\@elt{\advance\count@\@ne}\topfloat \the\count@}]%
               [{\def\@elt{, \the\ht}\topfloat}]%
}
{no}\hfill}}
\pagestyle{foo}

\makeatother

\def\a{One two three. }
\def\b{Red, Green, Blue. }
\def\c{\a\a\b\b\a\a\a\b\b\b\a}
\def\d{\c\c\par\a\b\c\b\par}

\begin{document}

\d

\begin{figure}[!t]
\fbox{XXXXXX}
\caption{jjj}
\end{figure}

\d
\begin{figure}[!t]
\fbox{XXXXXX}
\caption{jjj}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\fbox{XXXXXX}
\caption{jjj}
\end{figure}

\d
\end{document}
```

---

So instead of just using `\let` to save a snapshot of the latex lists use `\edef` to save a list which saves the height width and depth of the box.  then in the page header you can count the list as before or add up all the heights (plus `\floatsep` for all but the first) and so report the height of the top float area.

Doing the same for the other areas is left as an exercise:-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\textheight{20\baselineskip}
\raggedbottom

\makeatletter
\newif\iffootnote
\let\latex@makecol\@makecol
\def\@makecol{\ifvoid\footins\footnotetrue\else\footnotefalse\fi
\def\@elt##1{\noexpand\@elt{\the\ht##1}{\the\dp##1}{\the\wd##1}}%
\edef\topfloat{\@toplist}%
\let\@elt\relax
\let\botfloat\@botlist\latex@makecol}

\def\iftopfloat#1#2{\ifx\topfloat\empty #2\else #1\fi}
\def\ifbotfloat#1#2{\ifx\botfloat\empty #2\else #1\fi}
\def\iffloatpage#1#2{\if@fcolmade #1\else #2\fi}

\def\count@elt#1#2#3{\advance\count@\@ne}
\def\sum@elt#1#2#3{\advance\dimen@\floatsep\advance\dimen@#1\relax}
\def\ps@foo{%
\def\@oddhead{%
T: \iftopfloat{yes
               [{\count@\z@ \let\@elt\count@elt \topfloat \the\count@}]%
               [{\dimen@-\floatsep \let\@elt\sum@elt \topfloat size of top area: \the\dimen@}]%
}
{no}\hfill}}
\pagestyle{foo}

\makeatother

\def\a{One two three. }
\def\b{Red, Green, Blue. }
\def\c{\a\a\b\b\a\a\a\b\b\b\a}
\def\d{\c\c\par\a\b\c\b\par}

\begin{document}

\d

\begin{figure}[!t]
\fbox{XXXXXX}
\caption{jjj}
\end{figure}

\d
\begin{figure}[!t]
\fbox{XXXXXX}
\caption{jjj}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\fbox{XXXXXX}
\caption{jjj}
\end{figure}

\d
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I basically hook into the header with a `ps@` definition that includes the tikz code (rather than the traditional picture put commands). Alan suggested the `\iffloatpage` etc from fancyhdr. These worked well but I can't seem to figure where the package hooks. I would appreciate it if you maybe have a look and add a comment or two on the mechanics.

Comment: just looked at fancyhdr, too long for a comment will add to answer

Answer (score 4):

Based on Alan Munn's comment, I tried the conditionals from `fancyhdr`. These worked well.
There are three conditionals, `\iftopfloat`, `\ifbottomfloat`, `\iffloatpage`.

To conditionally draw the line using TikZ,

```
\iftopfloat{%
\draw [dim,|<->|] (1in+\innermargin-0.3cm, \paperheight-1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep)-- ++(0,-\topfraction\textheight) node[left,text width=1.5cm,text ragged] at ++ (0,0.4\textheight) {top\\ fraction\\ \topfraction}}{};
\draw[dim,|-|] ( (1in+\innermargin+0.3cm,\paperheight-1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\topfraction\textheight) -- ++(0,-\textfloatsep);
```