# Figure and floats wider than \textwidth placed differently in odd and even page

Tags: floats, margins

I have different margins in odd/even pages (set with `inner` and `outer` in `geometry`), and I want to use the extra outer margin to give more space to figures, tables and possibly some other floats, so that they are aligned to the inner margin. Moreover, I want this to be done automatically.

I have read a number of Q&A on wide figures, but usually the problem is about centering the figure with respect to the text.

Comment: See if `adjustwidth` environment defined in the `changepage` can help you. Foe showing an example, please provide MWE which reproduce your problem.

Comment: latex out of the box does not support this as the float is set before it is known on which page it will be placed but I posted an answer here a while ago that allowed you to save two versions and use different setting on odd and even, I'll find it...

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56017/formatting-floats-differently-based-on-placement/87861#87861

Comment: actually odd/even is easier than top/bottom so John's answer below is better than the link I give above but I'll leave the link there as it's related.

Comment: It seems that putting the content of the float into the environment `adjustwidth*` solves the problem pretty well

Answer (score 1):

The ifoddpage package can be used inside a float.  It takes two runs to transfer the information via the aux file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\linewidth}% fill entire page
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage
  This is an odd page.
\else
  This is an even page.
 \fi
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\linewidth}% fill entire page
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage
  This is an odd page.
\else
  This is an even page.
 \fi
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```